# Pointers to functions / Function Tables

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, macros, c-preprocessor

I am learning about function pointers and came across the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// A macro to define dummy functions:
#define DF(N) void N() { \
    cout << "function " #N " called ... " << endl; }

DF(a); DF(b); DF(c); DF(d); DF(e); DF(f); DF(g);

void (*func_table[])() = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}; 

int main(){
    while(1){
        cout << "press a key from 'a' to 'g' " 
        "or q to quit"<< endl;
        char c, cr;
        cin.get(c); cin.get(cr); // second one for CR
        if ( c == 'q')
        break;
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'g')
        continue;
        (*func_table[c-'a'])();
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how the pointer to function func_table works? In particular what is the effect of having a,b,c,d,e,f,g inside `{}` and what that whole expression is doing?

Usually when I see a pointer to a function you initialize the pointer by assigning the function name, but in this example it is just provided with an array of characters. So how does it know to call DF(char)?

Also, I am not sure why I needed to have the statements:

```
DF(a); DF(b); DF(c); DF(d); DF(e); DF(f); DF(g);
```

Also, with the statement: `(*func_table[c-'a'])();`
The reason why we are subtracting 'a' is because that different will determine the correct letter to choose from the array `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is some ugly, obfuscated code, it's not a shame it confuses you. Let's do it piece by piece:

```
// A macro to define dummy functions:
#define DF(N) void N() { \
    cout << "function " #N " called ... " << endl; }

DF(a);
```

If you expand that macro invocation, you get:

```
void a() { 
    cout << "function a called ... " << endl; }
```

And similar for b, c and so on. So `a` through `g` are functions printing their own name, nothing more.

```
void (*func_table[])() = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
```

That's easier to read with a typedef:

```
typedef void (*FuncPtr)(); //FuncPtr is a function pointer to functions of type void X();
FuncPtr func_table[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
```

And actually, that is `{&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g}` - the author makes use of the implicit function-to-function-pointer conversion. Meaning: `func_table` is an array of function pointers to `a` through `g`

```
int main(){
    while(1){
        cout << "press a key from 'a' to 'g' " 
        "or q to quit"<< endl;
        char c, cr;
        cin.get(c); cin.get(cr); // second one for CR
        if ( c == 'q')
        break;
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'g')
        continue;
```

This should be clear. Now the call:

```
    (*func_table[c-'a'])();
```

`c-'a'` is the offset from `'a'`, meaning 0 for 'a', 1 for 'b' and so on. For example, if c is 'd', this line calls `(*func_table['d'-'a'])()`, wich is `*(func_table[3])()` wich is just `d` - so that line just calls the function with the name you just typed.

Comment: I think I get it now.

So the macro #define DF(N) void N() { / .... will create a new function with the name (N) so DF(a) = a().

Since we pass function names without the argument list into a function pointer that is why we have the array of functions {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} which are actually {a(), b(), c(), d(), e(), f(), g()} 

Thanks for your patience and willingness to explain the code I really appreciate it.

- Marco

Comment: actually, the function pointer array is `{&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &g}` - the author makes use of the implicit function-to-function-pointer conversion. `{a(), b(), c()}` would be an array of function call results.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
#define DF(N) void N() { \
    cout << "function " #N " called ... " << endl; }
```

defines a new function with the name `N`. This works, because a macro simply creates a textual replacement so when the compiler sees it, it sees a perfectly valid function with the name `N`, as if you had typed the function

```
 void a() {\... }
```

and here there are the functions declared with the above macro, named `a-g`

```
DF(a); DF(b); DF(c); DF(d); DF(e); DF(f); DF(g);
```

Here:

```
void (*func_table[])() = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
```

The above declared functions are simply assigned.

The reason why you are subtracting the character is to get an index 0-n into the array of functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually when I see a pointer to a function you initialize the pointer
>   by assigning the function name, but in this example it is just
>   provided with an array of characters. So how does it know to call
>   DF(char)?

Actually, it's not given an array of characters, but an array of function. `DF(a)` will define a function nammed `a`.

So basically, you end up having an array of function pointers pointing on your functions (ie, `a`, `b`, `c`, ...).

The reason we're substracting 'a' is because, if the user pressed the `b` key, we'll want to call the `b` function.
Your variable `c` will have 'b' as a value. 'b' - 'a' = 1. It will therefore call the second function pointer of your array, (because array[1] is the second element), which is, indeed the function nammed `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly Ugly...

`DF(N)` creates a N function outputting "N" (use of # operator in macro)

so:

```
 DF(a);
```

is a shorter way to write

```
 void a(){cout << "function Acalled" << endl;}
```

Now they're stored in an array :

```
func_table[0]()
```

is equivalent to

```
a()
```

Using characters `c-'a'` is making a difference between two chars: `'a' - 'a' = 0`

Calling `func_tables[c-'a']` will then call the expected function.